# Statewise Ratio Calculation in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have data that is down to the zip code level. 
Each data point is a location and each location has a number of stalls.

I want to make a calculation that shows the ratio between the location and the number of stalls at that location.

I want this to be filtered state-wise for visualization.

Can you suggest how do i go about it ?

Comment: post a little (simplified) sample data and the difference between what you are calculating and what you wish you were calculating.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a calculated measure field with your stall/location ratio,
then make sure your state field is assigned to the State geographic role.
Double click on State to place it the latitude and longitude on the report,
then drag your ratio calculation onto Color. See if that works.